# Save and load complete MATLAB working environment

Tags: matlab

I have a few projects I work on using MATLAB.
I would like to be able to switch between these projects and have MATLAB open just as I left it. Same scripts open, working directory set, workspace variables set, etc. (what I'm calling 'environment').
When I switch to another project, I'd like the current environment to be saved, and the other to be opened just as I left it.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the variables can be save using MATLAB's [`save()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html).

Regarding the other things you'll need to create a script for each workspace.
The script will move to appropriate folder using [`cd()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html), open files using [`edit()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/edit.html) and load variables using [`load()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this FEX submission](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34577-savecurrenteditorfiles) to save the current editor state.  It uses a lot of undocumented stuff so needs to be used with care.

YOu can combine that with some other code for saving vars, current dir etc...